# Mudar cor so do elemento clicado (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

Preciso mudar a cor só do elemento que foi clicado, no caso mudar a cor de fundo da DIV, tenho um ng-repeat, porém ao clicar na div, todas as demais tem o background trocado.

```
<div class="cartoes" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="isActive=!isActive" ng-repeat="item in vm.data.cartoes track by $index" ng-hide="vm.data.cartaoAtivo.proxy == item.proxy">
        <div class="row lista">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <span class="cartao">{{'MY_CARDS.PREPAID_CARD' | translate }} {{ item.number }} </span></br>
                <span class="validade">{{'MY_CARDS.CARD_EXPIRING_DATE' | translate }} {{ item.validade }} </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                <span class="ativo">{{ item.status.description }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

efetuo a troca da cor das div com a seguinte sentença `ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="isActive=!isActive"`

Comment: Mas no seu html está fechando a tag div class cartões corretamente?

Comment: sim, e acabei colocando aqui errado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com o seu código, pelo menos não com a base dele que foi postado aqui.

Certifique-se de estar fechando todas as *tags*, de estar usando a variável **`isActive`** apenas dentro dos *loops* e de que não há nenhuma outra parte do código modificando os elementos.

Veja seu código funcionando:

```js
const fnController = function() {
  this.data = {};
  this.data.cartoes = [1, 2, 3, 4];
};

angular.module('app', []).controller('mainController', fnController);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: azure;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController as vm">
    <div ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-repeat="item in vm.data.cartoes track by $index" ng-  ng-click="isActive=!isActive">
      Clique aqui
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edição pra atender a necessidade da pergunta camaleão**

```js
const fnController = function() {
  this.data = {};
  this.data.cartoes = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
  
  this.marcarSelecionado = function(selecionado) {
    for(const cartao of this.data.cartoes) {
      cartao.marcado = false;
    }
    
    selecionado.marcado = true;
  }
};

angular.module('app', []).controller('mainController', fnController);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: azure;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.data.cartoes track by $index" ng-init="item.marcado = false" ng-click="vm.marcarSelecionado(item)" ng-class="{'active': item.marcado}">
      Clique aqui
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: por exemplo , como faria para manter um elemento clicado e se caso outro seja clicado ele seja desmarcado

Comment: @MarceloBatista use uma variável declarada no controller como `selectedItem` e marque atribuindo o `id` a ela. A lógica seria `{active: selectedItem === item.id}`. Se não tiver `id`, use outra coisa.